# Criteria for monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm struggling to understand how to test for an identiy.

Take, the finite group $(G,*) = \{1,2,3,4,6,8,12\}$ where * denotes the binary operation of greatest common divisor.

It is my understanding that an identity does exist in the form $e=1$ as $\forall a \in G$ $a*e=e*a=e$. This would be true for every element of G.

Where am I getting confused as G is declared in my textbook as a non-monoid.

Comment: You should look a little bit closer at your textbook, how is the operation $*$ defined in this case? It's not always true that $*$ is the *normal multiplication operation*.

Comment: That particular subset of the integers is not closed under integer multiplication, so it's not a semigroup or a monoid. My guess is there is something more in the passage you're reading that might make things make sense, like a modulus or something.

Comment: Yes I can't believe I missed it. The binary operation * is in fact for the greatest common divisor. I now understand that G is closed under gcd, but surely the identity, e=1 still exists.

Comment: Identity, if existing, does not necessarily have to be 0 or 1. Different binary operations have different (if existing) identities. 1 is not an identity here since $1*2=2*1=1$, not $2$.

Comment: In fact, $1$ *cannot* be the identity, because for all elements $g\in G$ we have $g*1=1,$ but we *should* have $g*1=g$ if it were an identity. In fact, we can prove that since $1$ has the property that $1*g=1$ for all $g\in G,$ then there *is no identity* in $G$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to use the correct definition of the identity.
"$e$ is an identity" is defined as "$\forall a\in G, a*e=e*a=\mathbf{a}$", not $e$.

Hint: Use the definition of the identity to prove why we do not have an identity here.

**Please only read the hidden part if you still do not understand the question AFTER thinking about it carefully for some time.**

Being an identity in this semigroup is equivalent to (please fill in). Then prove that the (please fill in) property does not hold for any element.

> (Please fill in) is being a multiple of all elements of $G$.